# Word Automation: Replace an Image using C#

Tags: c#, image, automation, ms-word, replace

I'm trying to change text and images in a word document using c# and word automation. I've got it working fine for text where I do something like the snippet below, but I don't even know how to start for replacing the image.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Oliver

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...

private static Application WordApp;
private static object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
private static object yes = true;
private static object no = false;

...
object search;
object replace;

object replaceAll =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

object filename = SourceFile;
object destination = DestinationFile;

Document d = WordApp.Documents.Open(
    ref filename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing);

d.Activate();
search = "OLDSTRING";
replace = "NEWSTRING";
WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(
    ref search, ref yes, ref yes, ref no, ref no, ref no, ref yes,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref replace, ref replaceAll,
    ref missing, ref yes, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: Curious what sort of solution you are trying to make.  Is this a functionality that you are exposing inside Word add-in or it's some kind of batch automation from an external application?  If external, I'd rather go with overriding the WordML through OpenXML SDK for 2007 or just mess around w/ the xml if 2003 instead.  Much much faster and easier to do.

Comment: Just a suggestion.  Use VB.  It will make your life in COM Automation land easier.  As for replacing images, you may look into 'Ranges' and might be able to iterate through the text and objects in them looking for image object types.

Comment: @roygbiv: +1. VB is much easier for COM automation

Comment: @oktavakol: what are you trying to replace the image with?

Answer (score 9):

You can loop through the InlineShapes and replace the pictures

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordExample
{
    class WordExample
    {
        #region Constructor
        public WordExample()
        {
            WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private Word.Application WordApp;
        private object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        private object yes = true;
        private object no = false;
        private Word.Document d;
        private object filename = @"C:\FullPathToFile\example.doc";
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void UpdateDoc()
        {
            d = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref no, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing,
               ref  missing, ref missing, ref yes, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing);
            List<Word.Range> ranges = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range>();
            foreach (Word.InlineShape s in d.InlineShapes)
            {
                if (s.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                {
                    ranges.Add(s.Range);
                    s.Delete();
                }
            }
            foreach (Word.Range r in ranges)
            {
                r.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"c:\PathToNewImage\Image.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
            WordApp.Quit(ref yes, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
        #endregion
 }
}
```

Comment: Excelent code!
But if its possible to identificate a picture into the loop?
this is because i need to replace only one image into my automation project thanks in advance

Comment: I know this is really old, but the only way you can really tell shapes apart is by adding custom info to it. You can add a hyperlink and use the address, or use the `Title` or `AlternativeText` properties (these are visible in the `Format Picture` dialog, under `Alt Text`).

Answer (score 2):

I just copy some path from @Mario Favere and make more easy

- First create Blank Picture and Insert Picture into word Document

[image]

- Second need to add Alt Text right click on Picture

[image]

```
private object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
.....other code.....

// Change Image

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{

    if (s.AlternativeText.ToUpper().Contains("POTO"))
    {
        s.Fill.UserPicture(@"PATH");                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to replace a shape or inline shape ? This is a big difference!

For an inline shape there are plenty of examples on the net.
For a shape you can do like this :

```
    private object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    .....other code.....



        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
        {

            if (s.AlternativeText.ToUpper().Contains("FOTO"))
            {
                object A = s.Anchor;
                Shape new = Brief.Shapes.AddPicture(@"mynewpicture.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref A);
                new.Top = s.Top;
                new.Left = s.Left;
                new.Width = s.Width;
                new.Height = s.Height;
                s.Delete();
            }
        }
```