# Remove a image and put a text in your place - Word File with C#

Tags: c#, image, text, replace, ms-word

I have a word file with various paragraphs and some images. I would like to remove this images and put some text on their place, like: "Here was image 1". But i don't know how to do this. I have a part of my code but the text has been sent to final of the page.

```
Int16 imgCount;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object path = @"C:\File.docx";
object readOnly = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss,
    ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
    ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

List<string> lista = new List<string>();


for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{

    string temp = docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
    if (temp != string.Empty)
        lista.Add(temp);


    imgCount = 0;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ilshp in docs.InlineShapes)
    {
        ilshp.Application.Selection.MoveEnd();

        if (ilshp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
        {                        
            imgCount++;
            ilshp.Delete();

            //break;
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph prfo = docs.Paragraphs.Add(miss);                    
        docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text =  "Here was the image " + i + ".";
    }


}
docs.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128873/word-automation-replace-an-image-using-c-sharp?rq=1)

To answer, however, you are adding text after the current paragraph, but you can add directly after the range you just removed:

```
int imgCount = 0;

        Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = @"C:\File.docx";
        object readOnly = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        List<string> lista = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {

            string temp = docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
            if (temp != string.Empty)
                lista.Add(temp);

            List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ilshp in docs.InlineShapes)
            {
                ilshp.Application.Selection.MoveEnd();

                if (ilshp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                {
                    ranges.Add(ilshp.Range);
                    ilshp.Delete();

                    //break;
                }

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph prfo = docs.Paragraphs.Add(miss);
            }

            int j = 1;
            foreach (Range imgRange in ranges)
            {
                imgRange.InsertAfter("Here was image " + j++ + ".");
            }

        }

        docs.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
```

This will remove all of the image ranges, storing each range in a list which can then be accessed to InsertAfter, using that loop's iterator to track the image number.

You can find some more detailed explanation in the linked article, but the above code should help you solve your problem.  Note the extra foreach loop over the added list "ranges" which is doing the text adding.  Good luck!