# Replacing a placeholder image in Word using Word.Shapes

Tags: c#, shapes, cpu-word

i am currently working on a C# tool that replaces placerholder images in word-documents.
I using Word.Shapes to find the correct placeholder.
Everything is working fine except that the replaced image is placed on a totally wrong position in the word-document.

Placeholder:
[image: placeholder]

New image after replace on totally different position:
[image: New image after replace on totally different position]

Here the code for the image replacement:

```
float left = targetImage.Left;
float top = targetImage.Top;
float width = targetImage.Width;
float height = targetImage.Height;

Word.Shape newImage = doc.Shapes.AddPicture(Program.Path_TempQRCode,
                                            Left: left, Top: top,
                                            Width: width, Height: height);
targetImage.Delete();
```

I am pretty sure that the issue is somehow depended to the anchor.
I already tried the following:

```
Word.Range range = targetImage.Anchor;
float left = targetImage.Left; // Store the original left position of the image
float top = targetImage.Top; // Store the original top position of the image
range.Select();
Word.Shape newImage = doc.Shapes.AddPicture(Program.Path_TempQRCode);
newImage.Width = targetImage.Width; // Set the width of the new image to match the original image
newImage.Height = targetImage.Height; // Set the height of the new image to match the original image
newImage.Left = left; // Set the left position of the new image to match the original image
newImage.Top = top; // Set the top position of the new image to match the original image
newImage.AlternativeText = "";

// Release the selection
targetImage.Delete(); // Delete the original image
doc.Application.Selection.ClearFormatting();
```

But the approach with Word.Range doesn't work, too.

Has anyone else an solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you try passing `targetImage.Anchor` to the `AddPicture` method in your first example?

Comment: Yes, i added: 
var anchor = targetImage.Anchor;
Word.Shape newImage = doc.Shapes.AddPicture(Program.Path_TempQRCode, Height: height, Width: width, Anchor: anchor, Top: top, Left: left);

with the same result. newImage is on a differant place than targetImage

Comment: Can you try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61245958
Something like `targetImage.Fill.UserPicture(Program.Path_TempQRCode);`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for the issue:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWqTx.png)

The reason is the little blue anchor to the left in the document.
When I drag&drop the anchor to the absolut top in the document the image will replaced correctly.
If the anchor stays on a lower position the placement is wrong.
I am pretty sure that the coordinates i read from targetImage.Anchor are wrong related to this issue.

My current workaround is to fix the anchor position manually in the document.
Now I need to find a c# solution to identify and reposition this anchor in the runtime.