# C# VSTO Replace Image in Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, office-interop

i'm developing a Word VSTO Add-In to handle certain Template/Export Functionality.
For that, a set of Images need to be replaced at the click of a Button.

For the Replace-Image-Method, i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58587793/14668211) Post as a Template.

I slightly modified it:

```cs
public static void ReplaceImage(ImagePath image)
{
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.AlternativeText == image.ToString())
        {
            object anchor = shape.Anchor;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape newShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(
                Constants.ImagePaths[image] /* Image Path */,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref anchor);
            newShape.Top = shape.Top;
            newShape.Left = shape.Left;
            newShape.Width = shape.Width;
            newShape.Height = shape.Height;
            shape.Delete();
        }
    }
    foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inlineShape in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes)
    {
        if (inlineShape.AlternativeText == image.ToString())
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape newInlineShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
                Constants.ImagePaths[image],
                ref Constants.Missing,
                ref Constants.Missing,
                inlineShape.Range
            );
            newInlineShape.Width = inlineShape.Width;
            newInlineShape.Height = inlineShape.Height;
            inlineShape.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my Issue is, that no Shapes nor InlineShapes are found in the Document.
(I layzily debugged it with MessageBox.Show(InlineShapes/Shapes .Count) )

It did not work regardless if the image was in the "normal" document area, header or footer.

I identify the Images by their AltName.

Can someone help me or explain what i'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,
Oliver

Update 07/05/2023 14:27:
This is the Definition of `ImagePath`

```cs
public enum ImagePath
{
    TitleLogo,
    Logo
}

public static Dictionary<ImagePath, string> ImagePaths = new Dictionary<ImagePath, string>()
{
    [ImagePath.TitleLogo] = Path.Combine(LocalResourceBasePath, "Images", "***_title_design.png"),
    [ImagePath.Logo] = Path.Combine(LocalResourceBasePath, "Images", "***_logo.png"),
};
```

Comment: What's **ImagePath**?  Did you define it yourself? Can you include a definition of this class?

Comment: @OscarSun i updated the Post with the Definition of ImagePath. `***` is just a placehodler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't have your complete code, I can only guess first, and I can't test and debug.

And plz debug to check the return value `ImagePaths[image]`, is it the picture path you want to insert?

And the return value `image.ToString()`, matches or does not match the property `AlternativeText`.

The most likely problematic code is on the following two lines:

`....AlternativeText == image.ToString()`

`ImagePaths[image]`

You must make sure that the value returned by the *Dictionary* object `ImagePaths` with the key `image` is the correct path for the image you want to insert.

Use **StoryRanges** object to access the shape of each part of the Document:

```cs
public static void ReplaceImage(ImagePath image)
{
    //foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range sr in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in sr.ShapeRange)
        {
            if (shape.AlternativeText == image.ToString())
            {
                object anchor = shape.Anchor;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape newShape =
                    Globals.ThisDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(                            

                    // Should be ImagePaths not Constants.ImagePaths 
                    //Constants.ImagePaths[image] /* Image Path */,
                    ImagePaths[image] /* Image Path */,
                    //ref Constants.Missing
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    Anchor: ref anchor);
                newShape.Top = shape.Top;
                newShape.Left = shape.Left;
                newShape.Width = shape.Width;
                newShape.Height = shape.Height;
                shape.Delete();
            }
        }
        //foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inlineShape in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes)
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inlineShape in sr.InlineShapes)
        {
            if (inlineShape.AlternativeText == image.ToString())
            {
                //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape newInlineShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape newInlineShape = sr.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
                    //Constants.ImagePaths[image],
                    ImagePaths[image],
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    //ref Constants.Missing,
                    Range: inlineShape.Range
                );
                newInlineShape.Width = inlineShape.Width;
                newInlineShape.Height = inlineShape.Height;
                inlineShape.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the Paths are correct and are working. `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AciveDocument.Shapes.Count` is 0. Could this be because the Images are contained in the Header/Footer, or do i need to use a different method of accessing them when the Images were inserted by a User ? They're Part of a Template that gets loaded

Comment: @OliverKarger If the path etc. all are correct and only not found the Shapes in a document then Just use **StoryRanges** object to access the shape of each part of the Document, like my code show.